# Oculus Go Developer Mode - Installed apk successfully but it does not show in Oculus

Tags: oculus

I got a Success message after doing adb install of the apk.
However, when I go to Library > Unknown Sources, I do not see my app.
The XR settings for the project has Oculus as the SDK.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to install the Oculus utilities.

https://medium.com/inborn-experience/how-to-build-an-app-for-the-oculus-go-from-start-to-finish-with-unity-cb72d931ddae

It worked after that.